# Unit testing Microsoft Graph API using Mockito - How to code cover 3rd party API

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am writing unit test using Mockito but I am still unable to understand how to cover the third party APIs - I have a public API called **deleteApplication(String clientId)** and a private API called **getApplicationObjectId(String clientId)**

So inside my private method - I have a code which belongs to library Microsoft Graph SDK - Java and I need to mock it so I have a code coverage for below these two lines -

```
ApplicationCollectionRequest request = this.graphServiceClient.applications().buildRequest(options);

ApplicationCollectionPage appCollectionPage = request.get();
```

And...like wise I have this line in my public method - I need to mock this so that I have code coverage for this...

```
Application application = this.graphServiceClient.applications(appClientObjId)
            .buildRequest()
            .delete();
```

Is it possible to mock in these scenarios, if yes what is the best approach? I am using Jacoco for code coverage. Below is my public and private methods.

```
public boolean deleteApplication(String clientId) {
        
        String appClientObjId = getApplicationObjectId(clientId);

        Application application = this.graphServiceClient.applications(appClientObjId)
            .buildRequest()
            .delete();
        
        return application.appId == null;
}

private String getApplicationObjectId(String clientId) {
    
    String queryTerm = String.format("appId eq '%s'", clientId);
    
    LinkedList<Option> options = new LinkedList<>();
    options.add(new QueryOption("$filter", queryTerm));
    
    ApplicationCollectionRequest request = this.graphServiceClient.applications().buildRequest(options);
    
    ApplicationCollectionPage appCollectionPage = request.get(); 

    if (!appCollectionPage.getCurrentPage().isEmpty()) {
        
        return appCollectionPage.getCurrentPage().get(0).id;
    }
    
    throw new Exception("Could not find application resource.");
}
```

Comment: How does your testclass looks like?